# Is it possible to provide multiple files to NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two different certificates and I want to set both to NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS. I tried to set it in the environment variables but got a warning as below during the run and it ignored it altogether.

> Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `C:\support\Cert\Certificate1.crt; C:\support\Cert\Certificate2.crt`, load failed: error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error

Is there any way to bypass this? Or is it that we can set only one file per NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS?

I couldn't get much details from the official documentation - [NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=file](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_extra_ca_certsfile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation states:

> The file should consist of **one or more** trusted certificates in PEM format.

So concatenate your `.crt` files [into a single file](https://superuser.com/a/111832), and pass the path of that file to `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`.